# Can I add <img> tag using insertAfter() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can I add `<img>` tag using `insertAfter` in jQuery?

```
$("<img src="/static/img/icinfo.png"/>").insertAfter('#id_input_field');
```

It seems not work.

Comment: do you realise your string quoting is probably causing you an error? or is that just how you wrote it here on SO

Comment: Look at the colour-coding in your question. Ask yourself, why might your code be coloured that way?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlight here... This thing in your $() is not even a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because you are using quotes within quotes on your first selector.

```
$("<img src="/static/img/icinfo.png"/>")
```

Try using a combination of both single and double quotes:

```
$("<img src='/static/img/icinfo.png'/>")
```

Here I have used double quotes on the outer string (the actual jQuery selector) and single quotes on the inner `src` attribute value. You could also use them the other way around: single on the outside and double on the inside.

The quotes tell JavaScript what is a string and what is not. The code you have opens a string with `"` and then closes it when you define the `src` attribute.

---

You can see this clearly by how the syntax is highlighted - even here on Stack Overflow. See how the color of the text changes? The text marked in red is recognized as a string and the rest is not.

Answer (score 1):

you are having the quotes `"'` misplaced, you can use single quotes

```
$('<img src="/static/img/icinfo.png"/>').insertAfter('#id_input_field');
```

Comment: Don't just post code - even if it seems obvious, explain what you changed and why ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for pointing out, i was just editing the answer after posting it :)

Comment: Ah... I see we have a cowboy here :P See: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok but it's not properly quoted, consider this :

```
$('<img src="/path/to/image.jpg">').insertAfter("#id_input_field");
```

Alternative as well (create tag):

```
var img = $('<img/>').attr('src', '/path/to/image.jpg');

img.insertAfter("#id_input_field");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("<img src='/static/img/icinfo.png'/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('<img src="/static/img/icinfo.png"/>').insertAfter('#id_input_field');`

Try it this way. May work

Comment: Why "may work"? Give some explanations to add knowledge to the topic.

Comment: In response to the asked question, I formatted his line of code in a better format. It is always a good practice to keep your quotes("" or '') usage correctly.  Either single quotes('') for all  jQuery selections and than double qoutes("") for the inner selection like the src attr (example). Or viceversa

Comment: You may want to read [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Some highlights: try to add info about what you are doing and why. So in this case, you could move your good comment into the answer itself.